Rich black and black 100%
I want to print out my art but before that im stuck with black color.
For example, which area should I use rich black, black(C0% M0% Y0% K100%),black(C1% M0% Y0% K100%).
anyone help me?image1



1% C is worthless. While technically that may qualify as "rich black" since it's not just K, it's fairly pointless to use 1% of any color. Most rich blacks use 20-40% of additional colors.

The biggest question is, how much is (mis-) registration a concern? If it's likely (as in web offset) or possible, rich black with misregistration produces color fringing. I would avoid it where there's no background color. You can use just 100% K everywhere, just make sure it is all set to overprint so there's no knockout of the color backgrounds (which is also bad if there's misregistration of the color plates)

Read the linked question. In my answer, the section about shadows is the same case as your yellow background.

Thanks everyone for helping me. Someone told me just put normal black everything in this case.

Thanks everyone for helping me. Someone told me just put normal black everything in this case because the printer was RGB. But I don’t know how to use black for RGB and CMYK in general
